# Question on base system

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question:- A two digit number A in base 11 is one-third of the number formed by reversing its digits when considered in base 19. How many such numbers are possible ?

My try at it:-

I took A = 10*a+b

Assuming representation of A in base 11 to be (xy) , got the following equation :-

10a+b = y+11x

After that I let representation of A in base 19 to be (mn), and got
10b+a = n+19m

now, ATQ:-

y + 11x = 1/3 * (n+19m)

how do I solve it further , there are 6 variables over here and just one equation

Comment: Why pass to base $10$?  Write $A=mn_{11}$ so $A=11m+n$ and then we are told that $3A=19n+m$.  Since $m,n$ can only take a limited range, it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: mn is the representation of number in base 11, now in base 10 it will be n+11m as you wrote, now we want to reverse the digits of n+11m and then convert it to base 19, how can we be sure that in base 19 the representation of the reverse of n+11m will be nm.   I am confused on whether the decimal representation of number is being reversed or the base 11 representation of number is reversed ?

Comment: The problem tells us that reversing the digits gets us the base $19$ form, that is a given.  Thus, if your base $11$ number was $A=24_{11}$ we see that $A=2\times 11 +4 =26$ in base $10$. Reversing the digits, we get $42_{19}=4\times 19+2=78$ in base $10$.  And we note that $78=3\times 26$ so that's an example of what you are looking for.  It isn't the only one though.

Comment: Do you feel that the question is not framed well on what digits have to be reversed ? like in the example you gave how did we know whether 24 has to be reversed or 26 to be represented in base 19 ?  shouldn't they have mentioned that like the digits in base 11 representation are being reversed

Comment: I don't understand your interpretation.  Nothing in the problem suggests that we should first write the number in some other unmentioned base and then reverse the digits. But if you want to solve the problem under the other interpretation, go for it.  I suggest doing it my way as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the instructions: your number is
$$
a+11b
$$
where $0\le a<11$ and $0\le b<11$. You're also informaed that
$$
b+19a
$$
is three times the given number. Thus
$$
b+19a=3a+33b
$$
and therefore…

Comment: Representation of number in base 11 is ab, but while reversing the digits in decimal system and then converting it to base 19 doesn't have to necessarily give ba , then how can we write b+19a ?

Comment: @Fin27 The question seems to say to reverse the digits *and* to consider the result to be in base $19$. This is how I interpret the question and I can't see other ways.

Comment: Thanks @egreg , I feel like I am complicating the language of the question.  We can't reverse the digits of a+11b and then also converting a number in complete variables to base 19, right? so it has to be the reverse of ab in base 11 only in and solved in the manner you have done